# How to use laptop sim card slot?

Tags: linux

My laptop (lenovo T520) has a simcard slot.
I bought a simcard and it detects it.

However I fail to connect to the internet through the sim's internet plan
and I don't know the software to use to make calls with it.

A search on a search engine didn't make me much wiser either.

does anybody know how to use the sim card slot on a linux laptop?

Comment: We wont guess based on your description, there are several technologies, and with bad luck it can even be a Winmodem. I located a couple of Debian setup tutorials to your specific model and it is not a good sign both do mark as unknown the modem.